# How to install w3c validator on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, w3c, validation, w3c-validation, unicorn

I have configured Unicorn locally on my machine, I can also able to run it on console. What I want to know is how to install w3c validation tools like markup validator, css validator, mobileok-check validator and w3c-validator on ubuntu. And also tell me how to configure unicorn for locally installed validators. Official sites are little difficult to understand so please suggest me some other site.

note 1: People from W3C says "Unicorn can only get results from other validators through HTTP, which means I have to install the other validators on a web server (which can be installed locally). I can able to use Unicorn fully locally."

note 2: I followed this link(http://thecodetrain.co.uk/2009/02/running-the-w3c-css-validator-locally-from-the-command-line/) and have already installed css validator it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Check [HOWTO: Painless markup validation with Opera and Ubuntu](http://virtuelvis.com/2006/10/howto-painless-markup-validation-with-opera-and-ubuntu/)

Comment: I have successfully installed all four Validation tools from the sources on my machine. how to redirect unicorn to locally installed validation tools.

Comment: In Ubuntu, I installed the local w3c validator server and used Opera browser for test my page. You can open any web page in Opera and right click and select the "Validate" option. Opera has a DEB installer for Ubuntu. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an open source [step by step guide to installing it on Ubuntu](https://github.com/tlvince/w3c-validator-guide).